# Taskbar won't Switch Windows

Tags: windows-8, taskbar

When I want to switch windows by clicking the taskbar icons it won't switch. I was wondering if anyone has also encountered this before and what the problem might be.

Comment: You need to better describe the problem

Comment: Basically when I'm on a current window and then I click to change windows using the taskbar, it will stay on the same window.

Comment: does ALT+TAB still work to switch between Windows?

Comment: yes, but the taskbar itself does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the current window you are on is set to be 'Always on Top'. Check the option.

Comment: I should have been more clear. Its any windows. The problem is the switching, not just the current window. If I use the clear the screen, using the button the the right (don't know what's it called) and get a clean desktop, then I am able to click on any window and that will work. The problem occurs after that when I want to switch to another window from the current window.

Comment: This should be a comment.